# ASP.Net MVC return Json as IActionResult modifies the object key names

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

I have a class BasketItem:

```
public class BasketItem
{
    public long FoodId;
    public int Count;
}
```

I have a `AddToBasket` controller which adds items to basket and then returns the json value of `BasketItem[]`:

I'm using `return Json(items);` which items is of type `BasketItem[]`.

The returned json is like:

```
[{"foodId":6,"count":1},{"foodId":5,"count":1},{"foodId":4,"count":1}]
```

while it Should be like:

```
[{"FoodId":6,"Count":1},{"FoodId":5,"Count":1},{"FoodId":4,"Count":1}]
```

How to prevent `return Json` from renaming the key names?

Comment: The default behavior in MVC is actually to return pascal-cased JSON since it uses JavaScriptSerializer under the hood unless something is overridden.  There's no way to answer your question without additional details.

Comment: No, I don't think you do understand.   Your returned json is actually camelCased, not PascalCased, which is atypical behavior for MVC.  As a result, something in your code is currently overriding the default behavior and there's no way for us to tell you what it is because it is in **your** codebase.

Comment: And as an aside, camelCased is the industry preferred standard which is why a developer in your organization most likely set it up this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by using the overload of the `Json(object, JsonSerializerSettings)`:

```
   var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver(),
        };
        return Json(items, serializerSettings);
```